# NullInjectorError: No provider for D

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic-framework, ionic5

community, We have a problem with an ionic project, the error is this:

NullInjectorError: No provider for D!

This is the project information:

Ionic:

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 7.1.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 7.2.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 16.1.6
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 16.0.0
   @angular/cli                  : 16.1.5
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 10.0.0
```

Cordova:

```
   Cordova CLI       : 12.0.0 (cordova-lib@12.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 6.3.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.0, (and 20 other plugins)
```

Utility:

```
   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.4) : 0.15.1
   native-run (update available: 1.7.2)   : 1.0.0
```

System:

```
   ios-deploy : 1.10.0
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v16.20.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 8.19.4
   OS         : macOS Unknown
   Xcode      : Xcode 14.3 Build version 14E222b
```

attach images:

[Error in console localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMKFo.png)

the error indicates that is a problem with a provider, but it's doesn't indicate wichi provider is.

Please your help

I checked all providers, but i dont found the problem